# How do I add the movie clip inside my data object to the stage? AS3

Tags: object, compiler-errors, display

I'm currently programming a card game using AS3 and I'm using a data object to store the card data (Movie Clip Object, Card Value, and Card Suit). Code below (aceOfHearts is the name of my movie clip object in my library):

```
var aceOfHeartsCard:Object = {cardObject: aceOfHearts, faceValue: "ACE", suit: "HEARTS"};
```

I am doing this for all 52 cards in the deck. I am then pushing each of these objects into an array which I am using to shuffle and deal the cards. Code below.

```
cardArray.push(aceOfHeartsCard);
```

At this point, everything works fine. I can reference cardArray[0].faceValue and it will correctly return "ACE", etc. However, when I try to add the movie clip object to the stage using this code:

```
cardArray[0].cardObject.x = 0;
cardArray[0].cardObject.y = 0;
addChild(cardArray[0].cardObject);
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert aceOfHearts$ to flash.display.DisplayObject.
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Turns out all I needed to do was edit the first line of code I had posted above and add the word "new" before my movie clip name.

```
var aceOfHeartsCard:Object = {cardObject: new aceOfHearts, faceValue: "ACE", suit: "HEARTS"};
```